# How do I store the ratings in session?

Tags: c#, session, webforms, irepository

This is a hybrid (Web forms and MVC) .NET Website for rating doctors.  Below is my GridView.  The user can rate by clicking a radio button, the ratings should persist in the Doctor object, and the Doctor object should be able to display the current user's rating and the average user's rating.  How would I store the objects in session?  There is no logon.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Remove" InsertMethod="Add" SelectMethod="GetDoctor" TypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.TestApplicationDoctorRepo" UpdateMethod="Update" DataObjectTypeName="MidtermApplication.Models.Doctor">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDoctor" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceDoctor" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewDoctor_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="DoctorPicture" HeaderText="DoctorPicture">
            </asp:ImageField>            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorName" HeaderText="DoctorName" SortExpression="DoctorName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DoctorSpecialty" HeaderText="DoctorSpecialty" SortExpression="DoctorSpecialty" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate Now">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="1"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="2"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="3"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="4"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" GroupName="RateNow" Text="5"></asp:RadioButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField AccessibleHeaderText="Save Rating" HeaderText="Save Rating" Text="Save" ButtonType="Button" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="fave" HeaderText="Favorite" SortExpression="fave" InsertVisible="False" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Rating : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        TestApplicationDoctorRepo repo;
        Doctor doctors;
        protected List<Doctor> context;
        RateableDoctor DoctorRating = new RateableDoctor();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestApplicationDoctorRepo.InitApp(this);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            context = (List<Doctor>)Application["doctors"];

            if (context == null)
            {
                context = new TestDoctorRepository().GetDoctor();

                Application.Lock();
                Application["doctors"] = context;
                Application.UnLock();
            }

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        protected void SaveRepo()
        {
            Application.Lock();
            Application["doctors"] = context;
            Application.UnLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1. There should be a "SubmitRating" button

STEP 2. Create a OnSubmitRatingHandling...pseudo code below:

```
private void OnSubmitRatingHandler(...)
{
    IDictionary<int, int> Ratings = new Dictionary<int,int>();
    for(int i = 0; GridViewDoctor.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       Label lblDocId = GridViewDoctor.Rows[i].FindControl("lblDoctorId") as Label;
       sTmp = lblDocId.Text;
       DocId = Int32.Parse(sTmp);

       RadioButton rdr1 = GridViewDoctor.Rows[i].FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;
       ... same for rdr2/3/4/5
       if(rdr1.Checked) { Rating=1; } else if(rdr2.Checked) { Rating=2; } ...
       Ratings.Add(DocId, Rating}
    }
    return;
}
```

STEP 3. I don't know why you want save Ratings in Session but not in a disk file or database somewhere? but if this is what you want, then:

Session.Add("DoctorRatings", Ratings);

But, if you want to persists the information, try add to session a class which include user IP address (Since no login) + rating in session or application variables - such as "UserRating" below

```
public class UserRating
{
   public string UserIP = null;
   public IDictionary<int, int> Ratings = null;
}

private void OnSubmitRatingHandler(...)
{
... other stuff...
string clientIp = (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).Split(',')[0].Trim();
UserRating UserRating = new UserRating();
UserRating.UserIP = clientIP;
UserRating.Ratings = Ratings;
Session.Add("UserRatings", UserRating);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to store the ratings in Session, because users will be able to rate their favorites, and the doctors for the favorites need to be stored in session, so I figured the ratings should be stored in session.

Comment: Yes I can see that users are to enter rating for each doctor in the GridView - but after user enter ratings in the form, user probably need hit submit, then ratings would be saved on server side right? For example to calculate average ratings per doctor over some number of submissions?

Comment: The user will press "Save Rating" button after selecting a radio button.